# Redirect in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I have the following code

```
$scope.insertTodo = function(){
                    TodoService.post($scope.todo);
                    $location.path("/#/");
                    }
```

It should run TodoService.post() (and he does fine) and after that redirect the user to `/#/` location.
The redirect is not working. What am i doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change $window.location.href like this

```
var app = angular.module('RedirectApp', []);
app.controller('RedirectURLCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.RedirectToURL = function() {
    var host = $window.location.host;
    $window.location.href = "http://" + host + "/#/";
  };
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.